# Is it possible to alter the order of Controls being looped through in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

The following code loops through all controls in the current form and handles null values perfectly. My gripe with it is that it seems to follow the reserve of the tab order of the controls i.e. it starts with the last control and works it's way back to the first.

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
{
    if (C.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox))
    {
        if (C.Text == null || C.Text == string.Empty || C.Text == "")
        {
            setControlErrors(C, "This field cannot be empty, you must enter a value");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(C, "");
        }
    }
    if (C.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox))
    {
        if(C.Text == null || C.Text == string.Empty || C.Text == "")
        {
            setControlErrors(C, "This field cannot be empty, you must select a value");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(C, "");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reverse this order easily? It seems weird to see validation errors in reverse order of the form layout. Changing the tab-index seems even worse than this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use Linq, couldn't you?

Comment: It iterates the controls in Z-order, not tab order.  Front to back.  So you'd normally encounter the one you added last as the first one, tends to have a higher TabIndex.  Just reorder them the way you want them with a Linq query or iterate backwards with a for-loop.

Comment: @Jannik you're probably right although not knowing how to do so would leave me in a similar position to where I am now. I didn't know LINQ was that versatile

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant I need to study LINQ in order to do so, looks like it would be worthwhile!

Comment: The basics were not lost: for (int ix = this.Controls.Count-1; ix >= 0; --ix) { var C = this.Controls[ix];  }

Comment: That's another neat way to do it, thanks @HansPassant will consider this in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the controls by tab index like this

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                         .OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! How would you describe this approach? I've got a web background and this is unfamiliar territory

Comment: According to Hans' comment this is wrong, as not tabindex but z-index is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using following code

```
        var controls = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.TabIndex);

        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
        }
```

Comment: According to Hans' comment this is wrong, as not tabindex but z-index is used.

Comment: But if tab index is set explicitly then? If I give tab index 1 to the control I have added at last

Comment: The correct answer may not be what OP asked, actually esp. since he accepted another 'wrong' one. Correct would be `var controlsZO = thisOrWhatever.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(x));`

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(ctr => ctr.TabIndex))
```

Comment: According to Hans' comment this is wrong, as not tabindex but z-index is used.

Comment: I don't see why it is wrong. The question was: "Is it possible to alter the order of Controls being looped through in WinForms" -> In that way, it is possible. There was no preference set in the question for Z-Order, or to anything else. Even the Tag property could be used. And that will be still a valid answer. Hans said that the code in the question was about to iterate through according to z-order. So can you explain what is wrong with this solution? Especially since the accepted answer is the same.
So I wrote the same solution as other in the same time, but only this one is downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, we have a deal :)